# Need count of rows for each value type

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, case, where-clause

I have a table in format

```
SID LinkName           
A1  Link1           
A1  Link2           
A2  Link1           
A2  Link2          
A2  Link3         
A3  Link2
A1  Link1
A2  Link2
```

I need to display results for count of each link type in below format

```
Link1   Link2   Link3                   
 3        4        1
```

Pls advise.

EDIT:
Also If I need to display results for distinct count of each link type in below format. Like A1 -> Link1 appears twice but needs to be counted only once

```
Link1   Link2   Link3                   
 2        3        1
```

Comment: What's the expected result if link4 suddenly shows up in the table?

Comment: Why you need that format ? what happened if you add Link4 and Link5 ? it's not dynamic, just do a simple select count and deal with the display LinkName, total. I don't understand the upvote, no code provided,you didn't try anything, certainly duplicate question ...

Comment: Mostly it is needed for static data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you'd not put these in columns, but in rows as:

```
select LinkName, count(LinkName) as LinkCount
from table group by LinkName
```

...which would give:

```
LinkName | LinkCount
Link1    | 2
Link2    | 3
Link3    | 1
```

That way, if new link types show up, no big.  Will that work, or must they be in columns?  If so, you're likely looking at either a single count(*) and two subselects or a fairly convoluted self join or some case method.  Like:

```
select count(*) as Link1, (select count(*) from table where LinkName='Link2') as Link2...
from table where LinkName='Link1'
```

...or something like that.

Comment: In the first SQL Query, if i have same row twice or more (i.e. redundant data), how to i show count of only unique rows for a linkname

Comment: The assumption I make is that you only care about the LinkName and assume that you're otherwise just counting rows.  If you're not and need to count totally unique rows (looking at all columns to figure out uniqueness), then you could select against the pseudotable (select * from table group by col1, col2, ...colN) where you put all columns in the group by.  Messy, but should work (though it does beg the question of why you'd have duplicate rows in the table at all).  There are almost certainly other answers out there (like some compound DISTINCT thingy or some non-standard SQL) as well...

Comment: Table has duplicate rows as everytime someone clicks a link, a new record is created. So assuming persons click multiple links multiple times, i want to know no. of times each link is uniquely clicked.

Hope this clears the requirement.

Comment: If you don't care how many duplicate clicks you get, I'd suggest putting a uniqueness constraint on the table and letting inserts fail on duplicate (so they never count).  Otherwise, I imagine either your table growing super-large or regular maintenance being needed to clean it up from time to time.  There are other (more esoteric) fixes for this, but any DBA who likes normalized data will be unhappy with so much redundancy in your dataset.  In either case, I wish you luck!

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL, you can just do:

```
select sum(linkname = 'link1') as link1,
       sum(linkname = 'link2') as link2,
       sum(linkname = 'link3') as link3
from t;
```

EDIT:

If you want to count distinct `sid`:

```
select count(distinct case when linkname = 'link1' then sid end) as link1,
       count(distinct case when linkname = 'link2' then sid end) as link2,
       count(distinct case when linkname = 'link3' then sid end) as link3
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum(case when LinkName = 'Link1' then 1 end) as link1,
       sum(case when LinkName = 'Link2' then 1 end) as link2,
       sum(case when LinkName = 'Link3' then 1 end) as link3
from tablename
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It worked. 
Further to this if there is redundant data (redundant or same rows in table) 
How do i get unique count for each link ?

Comment: Update your question, including sample table data and expected result.

Comment: added. Need unique count for each link. Pls advise. 

And I agree for the dynamic result.
The query given by BJ Black is also good option to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

```
select Link1,Link2,Link3
from 
(
 select Id,Rtrim(Ltrim(Name)) as Name
 from Table_1
) src
pivot
(
  count(Id)
for Name in (Link1,Link2,Link3)
) piv;
```

which give as:

```
Link1   Link2   Link3
4        3      1
```

Comment: @PankajGupta Using pivot u can get result in columns